# Does Instagram Block CDN URL requests from Some IPs?

Tags: facebook, instagram, cdn, instagram-api

I observed recently that for some cdn url of instagram the GET request is giving >400 response.

https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/26184672_169643143794471_5913317750591193088_n.jpg

If I try same url from same code from local it works. so, does it block content delivery by IP address of the request?

Comment: Try to set a known user agent on your request, maybe...

Comment: Yes, tried that. doesn't work. I am guess it is IP based, because it works from other IP.

Answer (score 3):

As the 400 error could be interpreted as:

- Invalid URL
- Bad Request
- The request hostname is invalid.
- The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax.

You may try to :

- clear your browser cookies
- clear your DNS cache
- clear your browser cache

---

And retry to get the data again.

---

Apparently it is not due to cache or cookies,

So please note that in the specific case of Instagram, and according to [this issue](https://github.com/stevenschobert/instafeed.js/issues/345) the `400 error` could also mean:

```
{ "meta": { "error_type": "OAuthAccessTokenException", "code": 400, "error_message": "The access_token provided is invalid." } }
```

You may also note that according to [the rate limit documentation](https://www.instagram.com/developer/limits/) when the max. rate limit was reach Instagram will raise a `429 error`, and from the [same source](https://www.instagram.com/developer/limits/),

> You may also receive responses with an HTTP response code of 400 (Bad Request) if we detect spammy behavior by a person using your app. These errors are unrelated to rate limiting.

---

So my last advice is to evaluate if your production server may be considerate by Instagram as a *"spammy server"* (because of too much requests)

In that case, you may still try to [review your app](https://www.instagram.com/developer/review/) and getting an access token. But keep in mind, that if your app was reviewed you still have this Global Rate Limits constraint:

> Global rate limits are applied inclusive of all API calls made by an
>   app per access token over the 1-hour sliding window, regardless of the
>   particular endpoint. Rate limits also apply to invalid or malformed
>   requests.
>
> Sandbox              500 /hour
>
> Live                5000 / hour

Comment: It works on browser. I am trying GET from code. And the same code gives 200 running on local and sometimes gives >400 in production. (same url, which works fine in browser every-time)

Comment: Does your production server is connected via an ISP load balancing device (a routeur with a multi-WAN),not the same public IP ? In that case it is possible that one of your ISP or one of your specific network parameter will block connection while in the same time the other allow. (because in my opinion 40% failure is suspect)

Comment: good poing. but, no http proxy. same client node in all calls!

Comment: Double check the rate limit, and/or if you your production server could be considered as a "spammy" server...

Comment: We are not hitting Instagram API right? I am just getting the public image url.

Comment: I see that, but apparently the "spammy" is not specifically relative to the API , it maybe a security to avoid "web scrapper", so do you know how many requests to public image url does your production server will send in hour (an average value) ?

Comment: Ping the cdn of instagram give you this domain: fbcdn.net, so it appear to be the same as Facebook CDN, you may expect that Facebook CDN will consider that a burst of 33 request /second to get picture data, is near a DDOS attack... And that probably a security feature which ban your production server IP during the burst.

Answer (score 1):

you may want to send real http headers with proper user-agent, accept, accept-encoding, accept-language and maybe also if-modified-since and cache-control fields.

This way you will be simulating the same request your browser does and be in the exact same situation.

Edit:
Given the fact that the 2 machines used for the test are in different countries (and networks) it may simply be due to difference in network reliability.

You should also account that your 2 programs may be hitting a different server due to the content being hosted behind a CDN. (So, again, difference in reliability).

In the end they could've really temporarily blocked your traffic having detected  a bot, not human user.

What happens if you manually browse IG from the "blocked" machine? Did you check different urls?

If it works with a browser and not your program it's due to the fact your program is not sending all the required headers. (Maybe "Referer" header too?).

Comment: I am not passing if-modified-since and cache-control but I am passing user-agent and accept and content-type. but that doesn't how it would be error from one box and not from other with the same code.

Comment: are your machines in different countries?

Comment: yes, one is aws us region; other is local box running from India

Comment: Other Instagram url works! the failing url fails consistently. There are about 40% failures. Let me try with putting Referer and Origin - other headers like User-Agent I am already sending

Comment: then it's either that they're moderating your traffic or they have some malfunction in their CDN. By the way it would be more hepful if you tell us the exact errors as > 400 can have many meanings -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_errors